Custom TabBar with center rounded button SwiftUI
Here is what I am trying to do:

The screenshot is taken from a 14 iPhone.

I want to manage the layout like the first image, where all the spacing and circle spacing are reduced. How can I achieve the exact TabBar UI?
Code:-
import SwiftUI

struct TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection: View {

    @State private var selection: String = "house"
    @State private var tbHeight = CGFloat.zero
    
    struct Item {
        let title: String
        let color: Color
        let icon: String
    }
    @State var items = [
        Item(title: "folder", color: .red, icon: "folder"),
        Item(title: "eraser", color: .red, icon: "eraser.fill"),
        Item(title: "cart", color: .red, icon: "cart"),
        Item(title: "house", color: .blue, icon: "house"),
        Item(title: "car", color: .green, icon: "car"),
    ]
    
    var selected: Item {
        items.first { $0.title == selection } ?? items[0]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.title) { item in
                    TabContent(height: $tbHeight) {
                        item.color
                    } .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: item.icon)
                            Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            TabSelection(height: tbHeight, item: selected)
        }
    }
    
    struct TabSelection: View {
        let height: CGFloat
        let item: Item
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Curve()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: height)
                    .foregroundColor(item.color)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(
                Circle().foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(height: height).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .shadow(radius: 4)
                    .overlay(Image(systemName: item.icon)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white))
                , alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
    
    struct TabContent<V: View>: View {
        @Binding var height: CGFloat
        @ViewBuilder var content: () -> V
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { gp in
                content()
                    .onAppear {
                        height = gp.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                    }
                    .onChange(of: gp.size, {
                        height = gp.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                    })
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct Curve: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let h = rect.maxY * 0.7
            return Path {
                $0.move(to: .zero)
                $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX / 2.0, y: rect.minY))
                $0.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: h), control1: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 0.8, y: rect.minY), control2: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 0.7, y: h))
                $0.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 3.0 / 2.0, y: rect.minY), control1: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 1.3, y: h), control2: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 1.2, y: rect.minY))
                $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection()
    }
}


This answer might help: How can i make custom bottom tabbar in SwiftUI

@BenzyNeez, I've tried, but it still doesn't match my requirements. It continues to add extra space.

TabView doesn't offer the flexibility needed to control the horizontal spacing between tab items.
To achieve what you're looking for, you'll need to implement a custom tab bar.
Fortunately, you have most of the necessary in place, it just needs some tuning.
Here's a rough go at it:
import SwiftUI

struct TabItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let title: String
    let color: Color
    let icon: String
}

struct TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: TabItem?
    
    private let tabHeight: CGFloat = 50
    private let tabSpacing: CGFloat = 5
    
    @State var items = [
        TabItem(title: "folder", color: .orange, icon: "folder"),
        TabItem(title: "eraser", color: .cyan, icon: "eraser.fill"),
        TabItem(title: "house", color: .blue, icon: "house"),
        TabItem(title: "car", color: .green, icon: "car")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack(spacing: tabSpacing) {
                
                selectedTab?.color
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                        TabItemView(item: items[0], selectedTab: $selectedTab, tabHeight: tabHeight)
                        TabItemView(item: items[1], selectedTab: $selectedTab, tabHeight: tabHeight)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)

                    HStack {
                        TabItemView(item: items[2], selectedTab: $selectedTab, tabHeight: tabHeight)
                        TabItemView(item: items[3], selectedTab: $selectedTab, tabHeight: tabHeight)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
            .onAppear {
                selectedTab = items[0]
            }
            
            TabSelection(item: selectedTab ?? items[0], height: 80, tabHeight: tabHeight)
                .offset(y: -tabSpacing)
        }
    }
}

struct TabItemView: View {
    
    let item: TabItem
    @Binding var selectedTab: TabItem?
    var tabHeight: CGFloat
    
    private var isSelected: Bool {
        selectedTab == item
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            selectedTab = item
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: item.icon)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .symbolVariant(.fill)
                Text(item.title)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            .foregroundStyle(isSelected ? item.color : .gray)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: tabHeight)
    }
}

struct TabSelection: View {
    
    //Parameters
    let item: TabItem
    let height: CGFloat
    var tabHeight: CGFloat
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: height)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .shadow(radius: 4)
            .overlay {
                Image(systemName: item.icon)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .offset(y: -5) //shift circle up
            .background(alignment: .bottom) {
                Curve()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: height, alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(item.color)
                .offset(y: height - tabHeight )
            }
    }
}

struct Curve: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let h = rect.maxY * 0.7
        return Path {
            $0.move(to: .zero)
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX / 2.0, y: rect.minY))
            $0.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: h), control1: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 0.8, y: rect.minY), control2: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 0.7, y: h))
            $0.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 3.0 / 2.0, y: rect.minY), control1: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 1.3, y: h), control2: CGPoint(x: rect.midX * 1.2, y: rect.minY))
            $0.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        }
    }
}

struct TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestReorderTabItemsPerSelection()
    }
}


This overall approach could be refined further by making the Curve into a rectangle with a "lip", so that your background will be a single view, eliminating the need to match the edges of the curve to the color above, and all that dancing.

@Angrei G., Thank you! Your approach is working fine. However, I think we need to modify the code again because the center button is not functioning like a regular tab bar button. I have multiple views, and I want to display different views on different tabs, including the center button.

@ShamDhiman Which center button are you referring to?

Like we have 5 buttons, first one is folder, second one is eraser, and the centre button, and fourth one is house and fifth one is car

I have set up all five different views on separate tabs. –

By centre button you mean the big black circle or the cart tab button? Also, which are the views you want to display in your original code?

No, thank you. I have updated the code according to my requirements. Thank you so much, Andrei G.

Starting point
The shape in your example is actually the "bite" out of the tab area. Trying it in isolation:
Curve()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 70)


I would suggest, it works better to define the full background for the tab area, with an indentation for the round shape. This way, you can also round the corners on the left and right side.

Revising the shape
From your first screenshot, it looks like the indentation begins and ends with rounded corners. Then the main part of the cut-out follows the exact contour of the round shape.

An easy way to add curves to the shape is to use addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:). Using this function, you just pass in the points that would form the corners of the shape if you were drawing it with square corners, instead of rounded corners.

Since there is no gap between the round shape and the cut-out form, we can cheat. If the round shape is shown as an overlay (as you are doing already) then it doesn't matter if the cut-out part fills some of the area behind the shape.


So here is a revised version of your Curve shape that could be used as the full background for a custom tab bar:
struct Curve: Shape {
    let buttonRadius: CGFloat
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))

            // Rounded top-left corner
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - buttonRadius, y: rect.minY),
                radius: cornerRadius
            )
            // Curve into middle cut-out
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - buttonRadius, y: rect.minY),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - buttonRadius, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius),
                radius: cornerRadius
            )
            // Line across
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + buttonRadius, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius))

            // Curve out of middle cut-out
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + buttonRadius, y: rect.minY),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
                radius: cornerRadius
            )
            // Rounded top-right corner
            path.addArc(
                tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
                tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
                radius: cornerRadius
            )
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}

Testing in isolation:


Using the revised shape
In your original example, you are still using the native tab bar, but superimposing the round shape and the inverted "bite". The height for the area is being determined by measuring the bottom safe-area inset. It seems, the height of the native tab bar is included in this height.
Sticking with the same approach:

The inverted form of the shape can be achieved using .blendMode(.destinationOut) over a solid color.
To stop blend mode from burning into lower layers, it needs to be followed with .compositingGroup().
It is also necessary to apply .allowsHitTesting(false), to stop the shape from blocking tap gestures to the tab buttons.

Here is the updated body of TabSelection that works this way:
VStack {
    Spacer()
    Curve(buttonRadius: height * 0.5)
        .frame(height: height)
        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
        .background(item.color)
        .compositingGroup()
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
}
.ignoresSafeArea()
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    Circle()
        .fill(.black)
        .frame(height: height)
        .shadow(radius: 4)
        .overlay {
            Image(systemName: item.icon)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
}



A more versatile approach
I would suggest, if you want to style the tab bar then it would be better to replace the native tab bar completely, instead of covering part of it. This would also let you adjust the position and appearance of the other tab bar buttons. The answer to SwiftUi Change Tint of Unselected Item in Tab Bar explains how this can be done (it was my answer).

Thank you so much, your code also works for me.
